# simple SED replace

Tags: regex, sed, freebsd

Just attempting to write a script to do a simple regex replace in php.ini, what I want to do is replace the line `;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1` with `cgi.fix_pathinfo=0`.

Ideally want to avoid installing any additional packages so sed seems a logical choice since it is bundled with FreeBSD. I have tried the following but doesn't seem to work:

```
sed 's/;cgi\.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi\.fix_pathinfo=0/' /usr/local/etc/php.ini
```

Comment: `but doesn't seem to work:` can you add detail on what is going wrong? probably just create a file with sample input and paste the output you get?

Comment: You do not seem to need the escape symbol before the dot, use `cgi.fix_pathinfo=0` (this is a replacement pattern, not the regex search pattern)

Comment: @Sundeep sorry could have been clearer, nothing happens to the file, it remains unchanged.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew never enclose any script in double quotes, always use single unless you have a specific reason not to and are full aware of the implications of doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the content of a file in place with sed BSD, you can do that:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/;cgi\.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/;' /usr/local/etc/php.ini
```

That creates a copy of the old file with a .bak extension.

Or without creating a copy:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/;cgi\.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/;' /usr/local/etc/php.ini
```

Note that in this case, a space and an empty string enclosed between quotes are mandatory. You can't simply write `sed -i -e '...` like with GNU sed.